# Filter Pandas Dataframe by 2 counts

Tags: python, pandas, csv, filter, conditional-statements

I have the following pandas dataframe --

```
 1. A     John
 2. A     Juliet
 3. A     Joseph
 4. A     Romeo
 5. A     Chris
 6. A     John
 7. A     Juliet
 8. A     Joseph
 9. A     Romeo
 10. A     Chris
 11. A     John
 12. B     Juliet
 13. B     Joseph
 14. B     Romeo
 15. B     Chris
 16. B     John
 17. C     Juliet
 18. C     Joseph
 19. C     Romeo
```

I have to filter with 2 conditions:

1. Wherein the Employees (names) are 3 each AND
2. Where A has a count of 8, B has a count of 4, C had a count of 3

```
My logic filters for each employee being there 3 times --

unique_employee=df.loc[:,"Employee"].unique().tolist()

count=0
for i in unique_employee:
    if count==0:
        df2=df1[df1['Employee']==i].iloc[0:3,:]
        count+=1
    else:
        df2=pd.concat([df2,df1[df1['Employee']==i].iloc[0:3,:]])

How do i put in the second part of my condition too?
```

My Expected output would be where Company A would have 8 instances, company B would have 4 instances, and company C would have 3 instances AND teach employee would be there thrice--

```
A    John
A    John
B    John
A    Joseph
A    Joseph
C    Joseph
A    Chris
A    Chris
B    Chris
A    Juliet
B    Juliet
C    Juliet
A    Romeo
B    Romeo
C    Romeo
```

Comment: Edit the question to add updates, do not add them in the comments.

Comment: whats your expected output for this dataset? if i understand correctly, then only Chris?

Comment: @Datanovice I have added my expected output above in my query.

Answer (score 0):

The name of the column storing "A", "B", "C" is named as 'abc' in the below code.

Each ep is a group identified by the "employee" column. Using counter will return a counter object(similar to dictionary) indicating how many abc an employee has.

Then comparing the counter with the condition_dic(which is set beforehand). If it fulfills the requirement, it will be appended to the output list.

```
from collections import Counter
employees=df.groupby("Employee")
condition_dic = {'A': 8, 'B':4, 'C':3}

output = []
for ep in employees:
    if len(ep[1]) == 3:
        output.append(ep[1])
    else:
        cnt = Counter(ep[1]['abc'])
        if cnt == condition_dic:
            output.append(ep[1])

output = pd.concat(output)
```

Comment: else:
        cnt = Counter(ep[1]['abc'])
        if cnt == condition_dic:
            output.append(ep[1])

How does this read the values from column 1 (Company A, Company B, and Company C)? wont i have to reference that column somehow?

Comment: If these were called Company A, Company B, and Company C, then how would this work?

Comment: @RahulGeorge Then you just replace the keys in condition_dic with whatever value you want. e.g. condition_dic = {'Company A': 8, 'Company B':4, 'Company C':3}

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, but I guess you didnt understand my question. If it is "Company A" and so on and so  forth, how will this change? 

 else:
        cnt = Counter(ep[1]['abc'])
        if cnt == condition_dic:
            output.append(ep[1])

Comment: @RahulGeorge I saw your update to the question. In that case, you might want to first filter out all the employees that have more than 3 records. And then use a search algo to find out the position combinations. Leetcode might be a more proper space to look for such algos.